# Session expiring when uploading large files

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

My PHP sessions are working fine but sometimes while uploading large files (mostly videos which takes hours to upload), the PHP session expires. In this case, the user fails to upload a big video.

I have an AJAX call done every 15 seconds to get updates from the server. I thought this AJAX call would prevent the session from expiring, but still the session expires.

How can I prevent it from expiring?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time till your sessions expire?

Comment: A PHP session expires after 24 min by default. Check your php.ini

Answer (score 2):

add these to your .htaccess file

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 18000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 18000
```

session will expire after 5 hours.

Comment: whats the max time i can have?

Comment: max value for gc_maxlifetime is 65535

Comment: But its get logout. what else I have to check.

Comment: it gets logout before gc_maxlifetime?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',18000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',18000);
```

Although, it's better to write these settings in the "htaccess" file.